# Questions about Displacement and modeling

Tags: modeling, node-editor, displacement

### Question 1: these lines appear after I did those dripping drops. They do not look odd in the final render, but I wondered how to remove them.[image]

Question 2: the donut looks like made from Polyethylene. Please see the Nodes blew.[image]

### [image]

There is the final one, looks like a one-week-old donut. lol
[image]
There is the node.
[image]

Thanks for your time~

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The file is apparently too big to upload here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers found by myself.
1. there are duplicated vertices because I hit E and did not do anything then hit E again.
2. Aged donut because I forgot to give subsurface to the donut.

I hope this can help anyone who has the same problems. It is just so much to learn.